# Use OnChange function only on the cell that has changed

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm using the following script to provide the hex color code of column A:

```
function onChange(e) {
  if (e.changeType == "FORMAT") {
    var formula = "=GetCellColorCode";
    var tempFormula = "=sample";
    var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
    sheet.createTextFinder(`^\\${formula}`).matchFormulaText(true).useRegularExpression(true).replaceAllWith(tempFormula);
    sheet.createTextFinder(`^\\${tempFormula}`).matchFormulaText(true).useRegularExpression(true).replaceAllWith(formula);
  }
}

function GetCellColorCode(input) 
{ 
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
var cell = ss.getRange(input); 
var result = cell.getBackground(); 
return result 
}
```

I'm using `=GetCellColorCode("A"&ROW())` in column G. However, it spans hundreds of rows, and takes too long to update, as every instance of the formula updates when one cell colour background is changed. Is there a way to change this script so only the formula on the row where the cell background colour has changed is updated? I've tried using `replaceWith` rather than `replaceAllWith`, but it doesn't update at all. Thanks in advance!

EDIT: For further context, I need this speeding up as I also have a script in there that updates my filter (I want to filter out all green and red rows), but it seems to time out frequently so the filter isn't often updated:

```
function update_filter() {
  var col = 7;
  var filter = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getFilter();
  var criteria = filter.getColumnFilterCriteria(col);
  filter.setColumnFilterCriteria(col, criteria);
}
```

Comment: The event provides you with access to e.source which is the current active spreadsheet so its as it the event object has perform  SpreadsheetApp.getActive() for you.  So using e.source you can know utilize. getActiveSheet() or even getCurrentCell in order to acheive you results.

Comment: `function onChange(e) {
  if (e.changeType == "FORMAT" && e.source.getCurrentCell().getA1Notation() == "whatever" && e.source.getActiveSheet() == "Whatever") {`

Comment: What's the filter criteria?

Comment: @Cooper Sorry, I'm new to scripts - what should I be replacing the whatevers with? 

Comment: @TheMaster I'm using Sheets' built in filter. The criteria is anything that's not #ff0000 or #00ff00 in column G

Comment: If you don't know how to fill in the whatevers then you need to return to the documentation for those command and read it until you understand it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`active` range usually provides the range where change took place. Try

```
var sheet1/*renamed from sheet*/ = e.source.getActiveSheet();
var sheet = sheet1.getRange(sheet1.getActiveRange().getRow(),7);
```

The variable `sheet` is now of `range` type, which points to the active row's G column.