# How to trigger when inserted on particular form and add to another form if doesnt exist in google sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have a google sheet that has 2 tabs - `grades` and `rank`. The `grades` tab has a few columns. `id`, `name`, `subject` and `grade`. The `grades` tab contains just a list of grades from different people. It is possible that the same person (id) has more than one grade under the same subject.

What I want is whenever a new row inserted into `grades` tab, the script is triggered and scan the rows in `rank` tab. Find the row that matches with the `id` and `subject`. replace the grade on that row if the newer grade is higher. If nothing is found, insert a new one.

I'm not familiar with google sheet script. This is what I found so far to get notified when something is inserted into the "sheet" (can be any tab).

```
function setUpTrigger(){
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('on_insert')
  .forSpreadsheet("id")
  .onChange()
  .create();
}

function on_insert(e) {
// scan the `rank` tab
}
```

I can't find any example on how to trigger for particular tab only. This is fine if not possible as I can use 2 different sheets. many thanks for the help! It would be great if this can be accomplish by using `formula` but still, I don't know how.

Comment: You question does not described the ranks tab.  In fact your question describes the grades tab in two different ways so which is which?

Comment: One of the problems with the use of the onChange with changeType==INSERT_ROW is that it is triggered when you actually insert a new row and at that point there is no data in that row.  So I think you're back to having to use onEdit() but now how to know if it was a new row is a problem especially if sheets can be edited simultaneously by multiple users.  It may still be possible but I would need a more thorough description of the process and the person that writers the process needs to understand how the triggers work.

Comment: I think you maybe asking to broad of a question. Perhaps you should digress and write some code of your own and learn how the triggers work and then move on to designing a more elaborate system.

Comment: `e` contains the needed info and `active` contains the active row. https://stackoverflow.com/a/70395304/ But Cooper is right(that the inserted row is probably empty), you're probably better off using `onEdit`, then use the onEdit event's `e` to get the corresponding row and proceed.

Comment: the `ranks` tab contains the same columns as `grades` but the `grade` column is always updated with the highest grade.